# Winjs: A flyout inside a flipview does not stay active

Tags: winjs, windows-8.1

I made a flipview to navigate between pages, so I have a main page that contains the flipview and many other pages that I reference in the flipview so I can navigate between them.

Now I put a very simple flyout in one of the sub-pages and it doesnøt matter how simple it is or where 
I put it, it just doesn't stay open. It closes as soon as I click on it (and not only outside of it as it should be).

If I try and put the flyout in the main page instead it works.

Is there any problem with having a flyout inside a flipview?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is because your flyout is not a child of the body. According to the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br211726.aspx "You should add the flyout as a direct child of the body element."

Comment: Thank you so much.