# WinJS date picker inside flyout not being triggered

Tags: winjs

I have a WinJS flyout object, than gets initiated when a user clicks on a textbox. The flyout is used to display a date time picker for the selection of a user's date of birth.

The flyout initiates correctly, but I cannot access the date picker inside. As soon as I want to select a date, for example, the flyout automatically closes.

There is no code that hooks up into the flyout, like a click event. I've tried adding a z-index on the date picker, without luck.

Comment: I've seen this issue as well in some client's code... but not sure how they solved it. I'll try to ask them.

Comment: I had a [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20538358/winjs-a-flyout-inside-a-flipview-does-not-stay-active) but with a flyout inside a flipview. No answer either. I guess flyouts are very volatile objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of launching a `Flyout` that contains `DatePicker` when clicking button.

HTML

```
<button class="button">Hello</button>
<div class="fly" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Flyout">
    <div class="date" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.DatePicker"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
WinJS.Application.onready = function () {

    WinJS.UI.processAll().then(function () {

        // Add a click handler to the button
        var b = document.querySelector(".button");
        b.addEventListener("click", function (e) {

            // Find the Flyout and call show 
            var f = document.querySelector(".fly");
            f.winControl.show(b);
        });
    });
};

WinJS.Application.start();
```